# Multiple, different VLAN trunks to KVM guests (Linux)

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, vlan, bridge, trunk

I've hit a roadblock of sorts with an architectural challenge. I've got a server running KVM - which will feature a number of guests, some running virtualised firewalls and others, just plain web servers.

- The web servers need a single untagged VLAN interface
- The firewalls need a tagged VLAN trunk

Now typically, this would be straightforward, just add a bridge with `eth0` in it, add a few VLANs on the bridge (`vmbr0.1` etc.) - then allocate an interface with an untagged VLAN to each guest (or multiples thereof).

```
                             firewall1 (vlan 1,2,3,4)
switch ===== eth0  vmbr0     firewall2 (vlan 1,2,5,6)
                   (eth0)    server1 (vlan 7)
                             server2 (vlan 8)
     vlan trunk
 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

Now, this works fine if you only have a few interfaces that you need to pass into a guest. But what happens when you need to put 500 VLANs into a firewall. Its impractical.

So what I can't figure out is how to create a number trunks (with common VLANs and different VLANs), and allocate those to a guest.

The closest solution I've found so far is to create the VLANs on the main bridge, then for the servers, just allocate a single VLAN from that.

Then for the firewalls, create a bridge for each, with just the guest's `tap` interface in it, then create the untagged `vlan` interface for that respective bridge, and add it to the main `vmbr0` bridge.

The only problem with this is that the traffic exiting the untagged interface, is of course, untagged.

**Is it possible to tag traffic exiting an interface?**

--

Otherwise, how is it possible to achieve different trunks to KVM guests, that may have common VLANs and different VLANs (but never ALL vlans) - and be able to assign single untagged vlan interfaces

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A lengthy solution ...

So I've been toying around with different concepts and I think I've made a workable solution. Basically, there is a main bridge trunk (`bt`) that `eth0` belongs to. Then for each firewall VM has its own bridge.

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
bt              8000.002618895a72       no              eth0
bt-fw1          8000.000000000000       no              tap100i0
bt-fw2          8000.000000000000       no              tap101i0
```

At this point the tagged traffic from the firewall VMs will enter their own bridge for traffic to enter.

I then created VLANs for each interface that needs tagged traffic - and the respective VLAN on the main bridge for untagged traffic.

Eg. VLANs 1, 4000-4005

```
bt-fw1.1       | 1  | bt-fw1
bt-fw1.4000    | 4000  | bt-fw1
bt-fw1.4001    | 4001  | bt-fw1
bt-fw1.4002    | 4002  | bt-fw1
bt-fw1.4003    | 4003  | bt-fw1
bt-fw1.4004    | 4004  | bt-fw1
bt-fw1.4005    | 4005  | bt-fw1
bt-fw2.1       | 1  | bt-fw2
bt-fw2.4000    | 4000  | bt-fw2
bt-fw2.4001    | 4001  | bt-fw2
bt-fw2.4002    | 4002  | bt-fw2
bt-fw2.4003    | 4003  | bt-fw2
bt-fw2.4004    | 4004  | bt-fw2
bt-fw2.4005    | 4005  | bt-fw2
bt.1           | 1  | bt
bt.4000        | 4000  | bt
bt.4001        | 4001  | bt
bt.4002        | 4002  | bt
bt.4003        | 4003  | bt
bt.4004        | 4004  | bt
bt.4005        | 4005  | bt
```

Then for each VLAN, a bridge is created, that combines all respective VLANs from each interface to allow untagged communication between the main bridge and VM bridges.

```
bt.v1                   8000.2a8c73ad057d       no      bt-fw1.1
                                                        bt-fw2.1
                                                        bt.1
bt.v4000                8000.2a8c73ad057d       no      bt-fw1.4000
                                                        bt-fw2.4000
                                                        bt.4000
bt.v4001                8000.2a8c73ad057d       no      bt-fw1.4001
                                                        bt-fw2.4001
                                                        bt.4001
bt.v4002                8000.2a8c73ad057d       no      bt-fw1.4002
                                                        bt-fw2.4002
                                                        bt.4002
bt.v4003                8000.2a8c73ad057d       no      bt-fw1.4003
                                                        bt-fw2.4003
                                                        bt.4003
bt.v4004                8000.2a8c73ad057d       no      bt-fw1.4004
                                                        bt-fw2.4004
                                                        bt.4004
bt.v4005                8000.2a8c73ad057d       no      bt-fw1.4005
                                                        bt-fw2.4005
                                                        bt.4005
```

This now allows trunked interfaces to the firewall VMs, with only the VLANs I want on them.

Any future guests that need a single untagged VLAN only, can merely be added to the respective `bt.X` bridge.

Adding host IP interfaces is as easy as adding the IP to the respective VLAN bridge

Eg.

```
ip addr add 192.168.100.1/24 dev bt.v4005
```

### A helper script

As my `/etc/network/interfaces` file could rapidly end up being massive, I wrote a small script that allows for minimal configuration - but with the same desired end result.

In the `/etc/network/interfaces` file it contains

```
# bridge bt-c0-fw1 vlan 1 4000-4005 interfaces tap100i0
# bridge bt-c0-fw2 vlan 1 4000-4005 interfaces tap101i0
# bridge bt vlan 1 4000-4005 interfaces eth0
# bridge-vlan bt vlan 1 4000-4005 interfaces bt-fw1 bt-fw2 bt

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
  post-up /scripts/build-bridges.sh || /bin/true
```

Then in the post-up script, `/scripts/build-bridges.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG="/etc/network/interfaces"
DEFINERS="vlan|interfaces"
DEBUG=0

# Tear down all interfaces
modprobe -r 8021q
modprobe 8021q

brctl show | awk 'NR>1{print $1}' | while read BRIDGE; do
  ifconfig "$BRIDGE" down
  brctl delbr "$BRIDGE"
done

function run()
{
  if [ $DEBUG -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "$@"
  else
    eval "$@"
  fi
}

function get_vars()
{
  DATA=( $(echo "$2" | grep -Eoh "$1.+?" | sed -E "s/^$1 //g;s/($DEFINERS).+//g") )
  for VAL in ${DATA[@]}; do
    echo $VAL | grep -qE "[0-9]+-[0-9]+"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      LOWER=$(echo $VAL | cut -f1 -d"-")
      UPPER=$(echo $VAL | cut -f2 -d"-")
      for i in $(seq $LOWER $UPPER); do
        echo $i
      done
    else
      echo $VAL
    fi
  done
}

# Build bridges
while read LINE; do
  BRIDGE=$(get_vars bridge "$LINE")
  if [[ ! "$BRIDGE" == "" ]]; then
    run brctl addbr $BRIDGE
    run ifconfig $BRIDGE up
    for INTERFACE in $(get_vars interfaces "$LINE"); do
      ifconfig $INTERFACE >/dev/null 2>&1
      if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        run brctl addif $BRIDGE $INTERFACE
      fi
    done
    run ifconfig $BRIDGE up
    for VLAN in $(get_vars vlan "$LINE"); do
      run vconfig add $BRIDGE $VLAN 2>&1 | grep -vE "(VLAN 1 does not work|consider another number)"
      run ifconfig $BRIDGE.$VLAN up
    done
  fi
done < <(grep -E "^# bridge " $CONFIG)

# Build vlan bridges
while read LINE; do
  BRIDGE=$(get_vars "bridge-vlan" "$LINE")
  for VLAN in $(get_vars " vlan" "$LINE"); do
    run brctl addbr $BRIDGE.v$VLAN
    run ifconfig $BRIDGE.v$VLAN up
    for INTERFACE in $(get_vars interfaces "$LINE"); do
      ifconfig $INTERFACE.$VLAN >/dev/null 2>&1
      if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        run brctl addif $BRIDGE.v$VLAN $INTERFACE.$VLAN
      fi
    done
  done
done < <(grep -E "^# bridge-vlan " $CONFIG)

exit 0
```

I hope this helps someone else, I've spent DAYS reading and testing and this seems to be the most elegant, easy to manage solution.

There's some good reading here too http://blog.davidvassallo.me/2012/05/05/kvm-brctl-in-linux-bringing-vlans-to-the-guests/